# Paw OAuth2 keeps giving: NSURLErrorDomain error -1012

Tags: paw-app

What could be an issue with this?

```
Event OAuth 2 Request 'Access Token'
POST https://XXXX/api/v1/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json, text/json, text/javascript, application/xml, text/xml, application/x-plist, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, text/plain, text/html, application/xhtml+xml, 
---Body---
client_id=XXXXX&client_secret=XXXX&grant_type=client_credentials

Error OAuth 2 Request Failed 'Access Token' 
The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)
```

The URL I target is on IIS server (OWIN based OAuth 2 implementation), using self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is described in the framework as `NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication`, which makes me think that what your server is expecting is your SSL Client-side Certificate. Have you set one in the request's *Options* tab?

If so, this may be the issue, because while SSL Client-side Certificates are sent along with regular requests, they are not sent for the OAuth 2 authentication flow…

Comment: I don't use client-side SSL certificate, at least not that I know. The thing is, this is working in my actual iOS app and I can get the tokens correctly (using AFNetworking and AFOAuth2Manager). Thus is puzzling where this actually breaks in Paw.

Comment: Given the error, it seems like some authentication has failed… we also use AFNetworking for this kind of non-debugging requests